# Reduce opacity of jquery isotope-hidden elements?

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

How can I just fade back to 50% the isotope elements thats are not selected and prevent the scale animations as defaults?

Comment: How do you identify the 'selected' elements, and what selector (class?) applies to the isotope elements in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see a working example in [this sandbox' source code](http://www.hopfnordin.se/demo.html), based on one of David DeSandro's github samples, if I remember correctly. It can easily be changed to do all kinds of things.