# jquery-isotope : how to change appearance of filtered elements

Tags: jquery-isotope

I would like to change the appearance of filtered elements without hiding them (same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013874/reduce-opacity-of-jquery-isotope-hidden-elements) but the link is invalid ..), and without moving them (only 'obscuring' them).

I've tried to change the *hiddenClass* and *hiddenStyle* options but I can't understand how it works ..

```
$container.isotope({
            itemSelector : '.element',
            columnWidth : 90,
            rowHeight : 60,
            hiddenClass :'',                // seems to deactivate the current style
            hiddenStyle : { opacity : 50 }  // attempt to set a nex style
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you want to do:
http://isotope.metafizzy.co/options.html#hiddenstyle

```
$container.isotope({
    hiddenStyle: {
        opacity: 0.5
    },
    visibleStyle: {
        opacity: 1
    }
});
```

Comment: opacity should be set to a number between 0 and 1.  so 50% is 0.5, not 50